# how to append two string?

Tags: c++

i have one string variable `svcName="serviceName"` and i have to append `"Base"` this string at the end of `svcName` string. and store into another string.

Comment: char* or std::string?

Comment: How to think? How to be intelligent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <string>
std::string s = "abc";
s += "def";
```

Answer (score 2):

[string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)

Answer (score 2):

If you require more complex string building, you could also use an `std::stringstream`.